# esimport overflowerror indexing bulk CSV files in elasticsearch

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am trying to index elasticsearch using below esimport library. Input csv files are of 500 MB size.

I am using below code in command prompt in wondows 10 server.

`start python -m esimport -s 10.10.31.111:9200 -f C:\CSV\1.csv -i bdm_crm_eve -t alldata -d "|" -T 60000 -bc 5000 -m C:\Data\latest_template_1224.json`

I am getting below error and i didn't get this anywhere on internet. Can anyone help me with this please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. In `esimport.py` file in the package setup, CSV field size limit was causing this issue. I did some testing and provided the limit manually by changing `csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)` into `csv.field_size_limit(2147483647)`. This works fine now